# How to write aggregations in cosmos db similar to Mongo DB aggregations

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a set of defined aggregation in Mongodb for a collection, i want the same feature in cosmosdb. How to have a aggregation in cosmosdb for a collection.

In azure portal i dont see similar option.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations for Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL are similar to those used for relational SQL using a combination of Group By and one or more aggregate functions.

You can learn more by seeing the docs and examples for [Group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/group-by) and [Aggregate Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/aggregate-functions)

One thing to note is that Cosmos DB is not designed to do large-scale heavy analytical queries. Cosmos DB is optimized as an operational database. If you are looking to do heavy analytical queries you may want to take a look at [Synapse Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/synapse-link).